# How to change column data type of a tibble (with least typing)

Tags: r

Pipes and tidyverse are sometimes very convenient. The user wants to do convert one column from one type to another.

Like so:

```
mtcars$qsec <-as.integer(mtcars$qsec)
```

This requires typing twice what I need. Please do not suggest "with" command since I find it confusing to use.

What would be the tidyverse and magrittr %<>% way of doing the same with least amount of typing? Also, if qsec is 6th column, how can I do it just refering to column position. Something like (not correct code)

```
mtcars %<>% mutate(as.integer,qsec)
mtcars %<>% mutate(as.integer,[[6]])
```

Comment: `mtcars %<>% mutate_at(6, as.integer)`

Comment: Also, `mtcars %<>% mutate(qsec = as.integer(qsec))`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This solution is probably the shortest:

```
mtcars$qsec %<>% as.integer
```

The trick is to perform the cast operation directly on the column > no need for mutate() any more.

Comment: I get the error: could not find function "%<>%"
Has this operator been depreciated?

Comment: to get %<>%, do `install.packages("magrittr")` and load that package

Answer (score 26):

With typing reference to the column just once - the compliant answer is

```
mtcars %<>% mutate_at(6, as.integer)
```

Edit: note that as of 2021, `mutate_at` syntax [has been superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) by

```
mtcars %<>% mutate(across(6, as.integer))
```

To refer to column by name, solution with one redundant typing of column name is

```
mtcars %<>% mutate(qsec = as.integer(qsec))
```

NOTE:credit goes to commenting users above

Comment: `mutate_at()` has been superseded by [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).

Answer (score 10):

### Update dplyr 1.0.0

Tidyverse recommends using `across()` which replaces, as noted by @Aren Cambre, `mutate_at`.

Here is how it looks like:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(across(qsec, as.integer))
```

#### Important:

Note that `as.integer` is written without parentheses `()`